# RSpec assigns returning undefined local variable error

Tags: rspec

```
describe "#index" do

        it "creates an array of voices" do
            voice = FactoryGirl.create(:voice)
            get :index
            expect(assigns(voices)).to eq([voice])
        end

    end
```

I have the above RSpec, with the line `expect(assigns(voices)).to eq([voice])` to see if `@voices` contains all the voices as an array in my `index` action.

Current it is returning a `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'voices'`, but I don't understand why.

My index action is very simple,

```
def index
  @voices = Voice.all
end
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Turns out to be a typo.. It's the symbol `:voices` not `voices`

The correct implementation is `assigns(:voices)`